# How to fix python recursion function

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function which returns a copy of a list where neighbouring elements have been swapped. For example, swapElements([2, 3, 4, 9]) would return [3, 2, 9, 4].
This is my code as of now:

```
def swapElements(mylist):
    if len(mylist) == 1:
        pass
    if len(mylist) == 2:
        mylist[0], mylist[1] = mylist[1], mylist[0]
    else:
        mylist[0], mylist[1] = mylist[1], mylist[0]
        swapElements(mylist[2:])
    return mylist
```

When I run this function it only returns the list with the first two elements swapped, does anyone know why this function is not swapping any other elements other than the first two and how I could fix it?

Comment: `swapElements(mylist[2:])` makes a copy of `mylist`. In other words, `mylist[2:]` does not reference the original `mylist`.

Comment: As iz_ mentioned it is copy so its not reflecting in your original list so try this                     mylist = mylist[:2] + swapelements(mylist[2:]) or just use 2 pointers for referring the 2 elements to swap like swap1 and swap2.So call swap(list,swap1,swap2) and increment both by 2 with base condition as size of list.

Comment: Perfect, thanks guys. @Kamesh-Bakshi yes changing it to mylist = mylist[:2] + swap elements(mylist[2:]) worked thanks, I just had to also change the second if statement to elif.

Comment: As replied by @iz_ above, you are not referencing the original list by providing the parameter as mylist[2:], it is just sending a new list whose values are = mylist[2:]. To reference the original array, you have to send the parameter as swapElements(mylist). But to make your recursion work and to refer to the proper index in each excution, you have to also send an index position in your function call.

Answer (score 0):

In your question it says you wish to return a *copy*. Your function mutates `mylist` in-place. Additionally, `pass` has a return value of `None`. You can simplify the function like so -

```
def swap (a = []):
  if len(a) < 2:
    return a
  else:
    return [ a[1], a[0] ] + swap(a[2:])

print(swap([2, 3, 4, 9]))
# [2, 3, 4, 9]

print(swap([2, 3, 4, 9, 6]))
# [2, 3, 4, 9, 6]

print(swap([1]))
# [1]

print(swap())
# []
```

Comment: `pass` has a return value of `None`?

Answer (score 0):

I would let the recursion do the work and, if this is Python 3, do something less index-oriented like:

```
def swapPairs(array):
    if len(array) < 2:
        return array

    a, b, *rest = array

    return [b, a, *swapPairs(rest)]
```